# Apply ccclon with cccrm package

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the CCC - [Concordance Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient). ([Manual for cccrm package.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cccrm/cccrm.pdf))

My data are some data frame with a time column and two temperature column to be compared with each other. I have a header for time (T) and for the temperatures (Temp1,Temp2) as well. The values of the columns are: POSIXct for the time column and numeric for the temperature columns.

I tried to apply the `ccclon` this way:

```
library(cccrm)

CCC<-ccclon(dat, ry="Tempdiff",rind = "Temp1",rtime = "T",rmet = "Temp2",covar = "",rho=0)
  print(CCC)
```

but that gives me just errors like:

> Error in rename.vars(dades, from = c(ry, rind, rmet, rtime), to =
>   c("y",  :